# Is it possible to extract installed nuget packages from project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nuget, nuget-package

For example if I create new ASP MVC 5 project with Identity authentication and Internet template.
**Is it possible to somehow extract installed nuget packages from it so I can install them in another project so I don't have to check one by one?**
Why I need this.
I want to create empty project and I want to add dll references same like in internet template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assemblies are in the **packages** folder at solution root and the *packages.config* lists the installed NuGet packages.

But I'd rather use NuGet and let the tool try to determine the necessary dependencies. It may also automatically add necessary settings to your *web.config*.